# SROLLBARINFO.rcScrollbar is referred to dimesion of scroll bar itself or scroll thumb

Tags: c#, user-interface, scrollbar

```
SCROLLBARINFO Struct
    cbSize DWORD 
    rcScrollBar RECT 
    dxyLineButton DWORD
    xyThumbTop DWORD 
    xyThumbBottom DWORD 
    reserved DWORD 
    rgstate DWORD 6 DUP 
SCROLLBARINFO ends
```

When GetScrollBarInfo() return this structure, rcScrollBar is the dimension of scroll bar or scroll thumb?

**Update:**

Another structure from GetScrollInfo:

```
typedef struct tagSCROLLINFO {
  UINT cbSize;
  UINT fMask;
  int  nMin;
  int  nMax;
  UINT nPage;
  int  nPos;
  int  nTrackPos;
} SCROLLINFO, **LPCSCROLLINFO;
```

To detect whether the scroll thumb at the bottom, why this formula works:

**IsAtBottom = (si.nMax - si.nPos) < (sbi.rcScrollBar.bottom - sbi.rcScrollBar.top)**

What is the relationship between nMax, nPos and scrollbar rect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the coordinates (as a [RECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162897%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), so top, left, right, bottom) of the scrollbar itself (see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). In order to get the dimensions you would need to perform the subtraction (code snippet is in C++ but you could translate to C#):

```
RECT coords = info.rcScollBar;
LONG width = coords.right - coords.left;
LONG height = coords.bottom - coords.top;
```

You will also want to be sure you are working in the correct coordinate system (screen or client). I was trying to find what coordinate system you get back from `GetScrollBarInfo` but haven't found it yet. My guess would be it is in client coordinates, but I cannot confirm this.

Comment: Ok, thanks! What I do not understand is:
Why this code works:

IsAtBottom = (scrlINF.nMax - scrlINF.nPos) < (scrlBarINF.rcScrollBar.Bottom - scrlBarINF.rcScrollBar.Top)

Where ScrlINF is ScrollInfo, ScrlBarINF is ScrollBarInfo
As I know, the ScrlBarINF.rcScrollBar will always be same, but nMax and nPos will always change.

Comment: I believe nMax should not change (unless data was added to the scrollable control), but nPos will. nPos indicates where the scroll box is. You shouldn't need to check the size of the scroll bar. If nPos is at nMax, then you should be at the bottom. If nPos is at nMin you should be at the top. If you are working in C# though, I don't think you need to P/Invoke windows API calls. There should be properties on the control that has the scroll bar.

Comment: pstrjds: The fact is even the scroll thumb are at the bottom, the nPos is not equal to nMax. But with the formula above, it works. But I do not why.

Comment: @Martin - You should post a new question for your follow up question. You can link back to here if you want,  but it's better to have each question in its own post. It's been a while since I messed with the Windows API scrollbar stuff and I remember having issues with those values. Unfortunately the code I wrote is at my old job and I can't reference it now. Post a new question and I am sure a Win32 GUI expert will be able to help.

Comment: @Martin - no problem. Just as an aside, you may want to try the GetScrollPos method, this will return the position of the scroll box. If that equals nMax then it is at the bottom and can't scroll anymore. Check this [tutorial](http://www.functionx.com/win32/controls/scrollbars.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It's the dimensions of the scroll bar rather than the thumb.